# Need a way to limit DC voltage of MAF sensor output

Tags: voltage, diodes, dc

Hi I have an output voltage ranging from 0-5v that increase linearly.

The ECU reading the voltage puts the vehicle in a limp mode when the voltage increases over 4.6v. The modifications completed to the vehicle cause the sensor the read voltages slightly over that amount momentarily.

Is there a way the cap the output voltage to 4.6v without altering the linear increase in voltage the sensor reads up until the 4.6v

I thought a zenor diode would work but I am not sure

Cheers Luke

Comment: Have you considered using an op amp?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange by the way. The best questions are those that are very detailed and explain what research you have already put in, and what you have tried.

Comment: What voltage supplies are available?

Comment: Which year car is? If You limit voltage, then ECU will record another error (incorrect fuel/air mixture) after 4.6 volts. Oxygen sensor would catch too rich/lean and you got another fault code in ECU.

Answer (score 1):

If you want accuracy then consider using a precision clamp circuit: -

[image]

V5 is the input and can be a linear 0 volts to 5 volts signal as per your requirements. There are two active precision clampers; one sets the positive limit - V3 would be a DC level of 4.6 volts in your example.

There is also a negative voltage clamp shown but that is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal circuit to limit a voltage like you want would be use an active clamp. Such circuit is typically built with an opamp and a diode plus a small number of precision resistors.

The picture below shows the generic structure of an active clamp circuit.

[image]

This works in a way that when the voltage at Vin goes above voltage divider level the opamp output starts to go low and forward biases the diode. This causes a voltage drop across the input resistor and limits the output voltage.

The one thing to beware of with this type of circuit is that the input resistor is in series with the output and thus the load you put on the output can cause Vin to not equal Vout when the circuit is not clamping. A common solution to this is to use a second opamp in voltage follower mode to buffer the clamp output.